# How do I divide sections in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

how can i divide sections in tableview? below is the code i tried to divide but unable to get the sections..

```
#import "ipapbatch3ViewController.h"  

@implementation ipapbatch3ViewController    

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
    NSInteger numberofrows=5;    
    return numberofrows;  

}  

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rams",@"balu",@"praveen",@"sagar",@"faizan",nil];    
    UITableViewCell * r = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];    
    [r autorelease];  

    r.textLabel.text=[a objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];  

                         return r;  
                         }  
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView      
{    
    NSInteger sc = 2;      
    return sc;    

}    




@end
```

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, here's a small example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
    UITableViewCell * r = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];    
        r.textLabel.text = [a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

    } else {
        NSArray *b = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];    
        r.textLabel.text = [b objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

    }

    return r;  
}
```

Comment: Well the example shows how to divide a table into sections but it is bad memory management. You create tons of Autoreleased arrays. Those arrays should be created once and released in the dealloc.

Comment: @Cyprian, The OP asked how to divide in sections, I adopted his code. I think you don't understand what an autoreleased object is. You don't own autoreleased objects as long as you don't retain them and thus you don't release them, nowhere.

Comment: @Nick Weaver if you read my comment correctly I say you do release the array if you create it explicitly in the init. Correcting sloppy code with a sloppy code makes people ask more questions later, so it's good to point them in a good direction all the way.

Comment: @Cyprian this code is close to the code of the OP, who seems new to objective-c, as his name suggests. So completely rewriting the code beyond recognition for a newbie doesn't help. It's his pace not yours.

Comment: @Nick Weaver, I know you helped and your code was appropriate for his understanding, I was just making a point. Have a good one.

Comment: @Cyprian You are absolutely right if we leave the context of this question. I'd never write this code for my own apps.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem in the code above is that you never tell which section to inser new cell, and thus they all fell into the first one.  Look into the method cellForRowAtIndexPath you need to specify that the newly created cell goes to a particular section.

[Go through those example programs provided by apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318)

Comment: @toddler in objective-c : you should just mark this post as the write answer if it solved the problem, and maybe you just show us the solution.